# Some Issue while creating order with bundle product

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, create-order

I Find this script to create order in Magento programmatically, it works for a `sample product` and not for a `bundle product` .

when i launch this script the order has created, but with out price product and total price order !
Here is the script:

```
 $productids=array(2732);
 $email="mustaphanak@gmailcom";
 $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
 $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
 // Start New Sales Order Quote
 $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getId());

 // Set Sales Order Quote Currency
 $quote->setCurrency($order->AdjustmentAmount->currencyID);
 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
             ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
             ->loadByEmail($email);
 if($customer->getId()==""){
     $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
     $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
             ->setStore($store)
             ->setFirstname('Jhon')
             ->setLastname('Deo')
             ->setEmail($email)
             ->setPassword("password");
     $customer->save();
 }

 // Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
 $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

     // Configure Notification
 $quote->setSendCconfirmation(1);
 foreach($productids as $id){
     $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
     $quote->addProduct($product,new Varien_Object(array('qty'   => 1)));
 }

 // Set Sales Order Billing Address
 $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
     'customer_address_id' => '',
     'prefix' => '',
     'firstname' => 'john',
     'middlename' => '',
     'lastname' =>'Deo',
     'suffix' => '',
     'company' =>'', 
     'street' => array(
             '0' => 'Noida',
             '1' => 'Sector 64'
         ),
     'city' => 'Noida',
     'country_id' => 'IN',
     'region' => 'UP',
     'postcode' => '201301',
     'telephone' => '78676789',
     'fax' => 'gghlhu',
     'vat_id' => '',
     'save_in_address_book' => 1
 ));

 // Set Sales Order Shipping Address
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
     'customer_address_id' => '',
     'prefix' => '',
     'firstname' => 'john',
     'middlename' => '',
     'lastname' =>'Deo',
     'suffix' => '',
     'company' =>'', 
     'street' => array(
             '0' => 'Noida',
             '1' => 'Sector 64'
         ),
     'city' => 'Noida',
     'country_id' => 'IN',
     'region' => 'UP',
     'postcode' => '201301',
     'telephone' => '78676789',
     'fax' => 'gghlhu',
     'vat_id' => '',
     'save_in_address_book' => 1
 ));
 if($shipprice==0){
     $shipmethod='freeshipping_freeshipping';
 }

 $quote->setData('overstock_shipping_total', 0);

$quote->setData('overstock_carrier', "UPS");
$quote->setData('overstock_shipmethod', "Ground");

$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->setShippingMethod('overstockshippingrate_overstockshippingrate')->collectShippingRates();
$shippingAddress->setPaymentMethod('overstock');
 $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'overstock'));

 // Collect Totals & Save Quote
 $quote->collectTotals()->save();

 // Create Order From Quote
 $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
 $service->submitAll();
 $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();

 // Resource Clean-Up
 $quote = $customer = $service = null;
 echo $increment_id;
 // Finished
 return $increment_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add bundle product with more than one parameter:

change

```
$quote->addProduct($product,new Varien_Object(array('qty'   => 1)));
```

to

```
$quote->addProduct($product,$params);
```

$params explained here:
http://inchoo.net/magento/programatically-add-bundle-product-to-cart-n-magento/